# ExecutorService - running tasks in parallel and save results

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to send a ping for up to 10 users at the same time, and update the user object with the result once the ping is done.

In order to do this, I am trying to use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

I started with a code like this:

```
private void pingUsers(List<User> userList) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    final int NUM_THREADS = 10;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

    for (User user : userList) {
        SnmpPingDevice pingUser = new PingUser(user);
        Future<Boolean> isUserActive = executor.submit(pingUser);
        user.isActive = isUserActive.get() ; // -- I guess it will block other pings and i'm back to my starting point where I need to run the pings in parallel.
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to terminate executor");
    }
}
```

This is how my PingUser class look like:

```
@Override
    public Boolean call() {
        ping = new CmdRunner(toolDir,outDir,
                new UserOidWorkerPing(version,community,ip,logger));

        return this.isActive();
    }

public boolean isActive(){
        String cmd = ping.getCmdNoRedirect(); 
        String rc = this.cmdRunner.runShellCmd(cmd,this.outDir +"/dummy",false);
        logger.debug("PING was sent with cmd:" + cmd + ",rc:" + rc);
        return rc != null && !rc.contains("Timeout:") && !rc.isEmpty();
    }
```

And back to the same issue, that the pings won't run in parallel (as soon as the loop waiting for the `isUserActive.get()` to end)

Any idea what I'm missing? How I can make those pings run in parallel and save the result for each user in my `List<User> userList`?

Comment: `Future::get` is blocking operation so you submit a new task after the previous is finished. Consider using [`ExecutorService::invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking your execution for each call, with this line:

```
user.isActive = isUserActive.get() ;
```

This effectively *waits* for the call to end, and does this for each call, on at a time.

You should rather submit all tasks, and build a list of `Future`s, to only wait for results when all tasks have been submitted. Something like this:

```
List<Future<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (User user : userList) {
    SnmpPingDevice pingUser = new PingUser(user);
    tasks.add(executor.submit(pingUser));
}

for(Future<Boolean> task: tasks) {
    //use the result... OK to get() here.
}
```

Comment: With this approach, How then you associate each result with the proper user?

Comment: @TheUnreal The list will be in the same order as `userList`.

Answer (score 3):

`Future::get` is a blocking operation so the invoking thread will be blocked until the call is completed. So you submit a new task only after the previous was finished.

Consider using [`ExecutorService::invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) which will return a list of `Future`s :

```
List<PingUser> pingUsers = userList.stream().map(PingUser::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Future<Boolean>> results = executor.invokeAll(pingUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add the `user.isActive = future.get()` into the `Runnable` you submit.

```
for (User user : userList) {
    SnmpPingDevice pingUser = new PingUser(user);
    executor.submit(() -> user.isActive = pingUser.call());
}
```